# How to sync mintty config from WSL2?

Tags: config, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dotfiles, mintty

I have .dotfiles in my home in WSL and I would like to use `~/.config/mintty/config` as the default mintty config. To do the test I have this minimal config file

```
BackgroundColour=4,8,230
Term=xterm-256color
FontHeight=42
```

I start mintty with the following:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\wsltty\bin\mintty.exe --WSL= -~  -
```

I have this behavior:

- **Work** if placed in `%APPDATA%/mintty/config`
- **Do Not Work** if placed in `%USERPROFILE/.config/mintty/config`
- **Do Not Work** if placed in WSL into `~/.config/mintty/config`
- **Do Not Work** if placed in WSL into `~/.minttyrc`

It seems only the `%APPDATA%/mintty/config` works in this case so I tried to create without success:

- A Windows Symlink to `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\user\.config\mintty\config`
- A Linux symbolic link from `/mnt/c/Users/...`

According to the MINTTY documentation it should use the following precedence:

- `~/.minttyrc`
- `~/.config/mintty/config`
- `$APPDATA/mintty/config`
- `/etc/minttyrc`

But... It doesn't...

How can I use my config placed in WSL2 into `~/.config/mintty`?